# how to find similarity for multi-word tokens? ex: ("united states of america", "united kingdom")?

Tags: stanford-nlp, gensim, cosine-similarity

I am using Gensim to compute the cosine similarity between two words. I am using following Stanford GLoVE 42B data set: https://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.42B.300d.zip

when i do this
`glove_model.similarity("united states of america","warm")`
i get `KeyError: "Key 'united states of america' not present"`

how do i compute cosine similarity between such two multi-word tokens?

Answer (score 0):

If the set-of-vectors you have chosen doesn't have any vectors for multiword tokens like `'united states of america'`, then there's nothing to compare. It's like asking for a token for some random made-up word `'pikslograble'`.

If you need good vectors for such tokens, you'll need to choose, or train, a model that includes such tokens.

If you already have training texts that include such tokens, and know a way to tokenize that text pre-training that retains the word-groupings that are of interest to you, that's pretty easy! But that's pretty rare.

If instead, as is more common, you don't start out knowing all your multi-word tokens, or have texts but don't have an existing way to decide when words are best alone (as unigrams like `'united'`), or best as groups (arbitrarily-long multigrams like `'united states of america'`), that's a much-harder problem, depending on your needs, which would require adding a statistical or grammar-sensitive tokenization step for creating just the right longer tokens.

One cheap cheat sometimes used is to create a synthetic vector for runs-of-words (be they short phrases or longer sentences/etc) by averaging together the individual words' vectors. In recent Gensim releases, there's a utility method `get_mean_vector()` ([docs, with useful options](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.get_mean_vector)) for doing so:

```
multiword_mean_vector = glove_model.get_mean_vector(keys=['united', 'states', 'of', 'america'])
```

The raw vector in `multiword_mean_vector` can't be passed into `KeyedVectors.similarity()`, which expects keys to look-up individual vectors. But the formula for cosine-similarity is very simple – you can look at the [source code for `KeyedVectors.similarity()` to see it's a one-liner](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ded78776284ad7b55b6626191eaa8dcea0dd3db0/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L1237) taking to dot-product of the unit-normed vectors – and thus you can get the cosine-similarity between the above raw `multiword_mean_vector` and another single-word vector by doing the calculation yourself:

```
import numpy as np
from gensim import matutils
csim = np.dot(matutils.unitvec(multiword_mean_vector),
              glove_model.get_vector('warm', norm=True))
```

But while this averaging may sometimes work better than nothing – it at least gives you a vector to try in later comparisons/steps – it generally won't work well. The meaning of runs-of-related-words is often very different from the words individually.

So per above, if you want *good* vectors for meaningful word-multigrams, you'll have to find or train a model that specifically creates them.

Answer (score 0):

While @gojomo covers the essence of the problem regarding single vs multiple word tokens, there are a couple options for getting vectors of numbers you can compare

- Use a transformer model such as bert to get the vectors for an entire phrase or sentence
- Use a neural constituency parser such as included with [Stanza](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza), "parse" the phrase in question, and read off the top layer of the final tree.  This will require some code changes, at least in the case of Stanza, since the model just throws away the intermediate results once it builds a parse tree